# Connecting to bluetooth headphones to audio sink

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, bluetooth, bluez

I have a problem with my Sony WH-1000XM2 headphones on Linux Mint 18.3.

I'm using Blueman and I was able to configure an automatic Bluetooth connection which works as soon as I turn on my headphones. Unfortunately, headphones are automatically connected to Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) and it's not possible to change it to High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink).

After automatic connection, the sound panel doesn't even have the sink option. Only switching between speakers and headset enables selection of sink but the change in settings has no influence. I have found out that the necessary step to fix this problem is to reconnect the device, either with a standard system Bluetooth manager or Blueman, go to sound panel, change to headphones and now selecting sink has an effect on sound output.

But as soon as I turn my headphones off for even a second, the problem appears again at reconnection.

I'm not sure what is the correct way to have a flawless automatic connection to Bluetooth headphones, similar to the one I have with my Android phone. Any ideas?

- Kernel: 4.15.0-24-generic
- PulseAudio: 8.0

Comment: This question most likely concerns the same problem, and now has an answer with a possible workaround: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126426/cant-switch-to-a2dp-sink/1154723